# Error when entering a words in array of pointers to char

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

This program checks if words in array of pointers to char `**s`(that you should load first) are the same as words in function `fun`. For some reason, I can't load words properly in the `main` function and I don't know where why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int fun(char **s,int j)
{
    int i, num=0;

    for(i=0;i<j;i++)
    {
       if(strcmp(s[i],"first")==0)
        num++;
        if(strcmp(s[i],"second")==0)
         num++;

    }

    if(num==j)
      return 1;
    else
      return 0;

}
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    char **s=(char**)malloc(20*sizeof(char*)); // alloc
    char ss[20];
    int i=0,ret;

    while(1)  // while string 'ss' is different from string "stop"
    {
       scanf("%s",ss);

       if(strcmp(ss,"stop")==0)
        break;
       else
     {    s[i]=ss; // if ss is different from "stop"
          i++;

     }

}

ret=fun(s,i); // returns 1 if words are the same as words in function fun

if(ret)
 printf("Matching\n");

else
 printf("Doesn't matches\n");

for(int t=0;t<i;t++)
   free(s[i]);
free(s);
```

}

Comment: You have allocated space for all the pointers you need, but you do not create any new spaces for them to point to.  All you have for any string *data* is array `ss`.  When you assign `s[i]=ss`, you make `s[i]` contain a pointer to the first element of `ss`.  Thus all elements of `s[i]` (that you set) point to the same one array.  You need to allocate space for the string data, too, and copy the data into it.  That can be `malloc` + `strcpy`, or on a POSIX system the `strdup()` function rolls those together into one.

Comment: There is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thanks. I solved it using `strcpy` function and posted the final code here.

Comment: @gaga - you cannot simply use `strcpy` without first having used `malloc` to allocate storage for what you are going to copy. Note, if you have `strdup`, it will both allocate and copy, otherwise you must allocate storage for each string, assign the starting address for the new block of memory to `s[i]` and *then* copy `ss` to `s[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
char **s=(char**)malloc(20*sizeof(char*)); // alloc
```

That makes room for 20 pointers to `char`. It doesn't make any room to actually store the `char`s.

```
s[i]=ss; // if ss is different from "stop"
```

Doing that in your loop will just result in a bunch of pointers to the same underlying sequence of `char`s. You need to use either a loop or a function like [`strncpy`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcpy.3.html) to actually copy the `char`s.

```
for(int t=0;t<i;t++)
   free(s[i]);
```

This should be an obvious sign of a mistake, as there's no `malloc` corresponding with this `free`. (Your only `malloc` corresponds with the `free(s);` below this.)

Answer (score 0):

Following all your instructions, I solved it using function `strcpy` for those who maybe has the same problem:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>

 int fun(char **s,int j) 
 {
    int i;

    int num=0,numm=0;

    for(i=0;i<j;i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(s[i],"first")==0)
        num=1;
        if(strcmp(s[i],"second")==0)
        numm=1;

    }

    if(num!=0 && numm!=0)
     return 1;
    else
     return 0;

   }

   int main(int argc,char *argv[])
   {
       char **s; //  pointer to pointer to char
       char ss[20];
       int i=0,ret; // i-number of words we entered

       scanf("%s",ss);
       if(strcmp(ss,"stop")!=0)
       {
          s=(char**)malloc(1*sizeof(char*));
          s[i]=malloc(20*sizeof(char));
          strcpy(s[i],ss);
          i++;
       }

       while(1)  // while string 'ss' is different from string "stop"
       {
           scanf("%s",ss);

           if(strcmp(ss,"stop")!=0)
           {
              s=(char**)realloc(s,(i+1)*sizeof(char*));
              s[i]=malloc(20*sizeof(char));
              strcpy(s[i],ss);

              i++;
           }
           else
             break;

         }  

         ret=fun(s,i); // returns 1 if words are the same as words in function fun  

      if(ret)
        printf("\nMatching\n");
      else
        printf("\nDoesn't matches\n");

       for(int t=0;t<i;t++)
         free(s[i]);

       free(s);
```

}

Comment: This is bad. It uses `scanf` and `strcpy` unsafely, which causes buffer overflows, a very serious security vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple solution, use `strdup` if you have it**

Your problem was you were only allocating `20` pointers. The pointers you allocate are uninitialized and do not point to any valid storage themselves. In order to store strings at each `s[i]` pointer, you must allocate storage sufficient to store `ss` (`strlen(ss) + 1` chars) and then copy `ss` to the new block of memory you allocated. If you have the `strdup` function, that will both allocate and copy for you, but since it allocates, it is up to you to **validate** the allocation succeeded, e.g.

```
#define NPTR 20     /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char **s = NULL;    /* initialize all variables */
    char ss[20] = "";
    int i = 0,
        ret = 0;

    s = malloc (NPTR * sizeof *s);  /* allocate NPTR pointers to char */
    if (s == NULL) {                /* validate EVERY allocation */
        perror ("malloc-s");
        return 1;
    }

    /* fill up to NPTR pointers with strings read from stdin */
    while (i < NPTR && scanf ("%19s", ss) == 1) {
        /* compare for stop */
        if (strcmp (ss, "stop") == 0)
            break;
        /* strdup will allocate for s[i] and copy ss */
        s[i] = strdup (ss);
        if (s[i] == NULL) {         /* it allocates -> you must validate */
            perror ("strdup-s[i]");
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

(**note:** you must protect your array bounds for `ss` by including the *filed width* modifier in your `scanf` call, e.g. `scanf ("%19s", ss)`)

**If you don't have `strdup`, just `malloc` and `strcpy` (or better `memcpy`)**

Without `strdup`, you simply get the length of the string in `ss`, allocate `length+1` chars assinging the starting address for the new block of memory to `s[i]` and then copy `ss` to the new block of memory. The only change to above would be:

```
    ...
    /* fill up to NPTR pointers with strings read from stdin */
    while (i < NPTR && scanf ("%19s", ss) == 1) {
        size_t len = 0;
        /* compare for stop */
        if (strcmp (ss, "stop") == 0)
            break;
        len = strlen (ss);              /* get length of string in ss */
        s[i] = malloc (len + 1);        /* allocate length + 1 chars */
        if (s[i] == NULL) {             /* you allocate / you validate */
            perror ("malloc-s[i]");
            break;
        }
        memcpy (s[i], ss, len + 1);     /* you have length, just memcpy */
        i++;
    }
    ...
```

(**note:** above, you have already scanned `ss` to with `strlen` to get the length, so there is no need to `strcpy` (which will scan for the end again), just use `memcpy` with the length you have `+1` to copy the *nul-terminating* character which will be slightly more efficient).

Either way works. Then to free the memory you have allocated.

```
for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    free (s[j]);    /* free storage for each string */
free (s);           /* free pointers */
```

(**note also:** the `i < NPTR` check to prevent storing more strings than you have pointers allocated. Instead of stopping at `i == NPTR`, you can simply `realloc` the number of pointers and continue on. The general approach is to keep track of the number of pointers you have allocated, and when you reach your limit, `realloc` to double the number of pointers (or multiply current number by `3/2`, or whatever you like), validate the reallocation succeeded, and update the current number allocated to the new number of pointers and keep going until you hit your pointer limit again, and repeat as required...)